# How to run a program until certain answer is given by user (string + #)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a JavaScript program (for recreational use) that asks a user multiple questions. One of the questions it asks is **"Do you like the color red (yes/no)?"** It pops up in **prompt box**, but I want the user to answer yes or no only. If the user answers something besides yes or no I want a prompt box to popup and say **"Invalid answer. Please enter yes or no only."** I want to have that message keep popping up over and over until the user answers yes or no. If the user enters yes I want an alert box to pop up and say **"My favorite color is red too!"** If the user inputs no display **alert box "okay"**. Sorry this is such a lengthy question, but I've tried everything I know to no anvil. Help would be much appreciated.

Code: (near to what I want it to do)

```
var qtwo = prompt(" Do you like the color red (Yes/No) " + name);

switch(qtwo){

        case "yes":
            alert("I like the color red too!");
            break;

        case "no":
            alert("Okay.");
            break;

        default: 
            prompt("Invalid answer! Please type only yes or no.");

                if(qtwo=="yes"){
                    alert("I like the color red too!.");
                }
                if(qtwo=="no"){
                    alert("Okay");
                }
    }
```

Should I have some sort of while/for loop in there to keep repeating the code until the goal is met which is a yes or no?

Comment: i don't see a problem with using a while loop in this case

Comment: "Should I have some sort of while/for loop in there to keep" Yup

Comment: also, why not use buttons or radios or something rather than typing if there are only 2 possibilities? Also, you might want to compare `qtwo.toLowerCase()` ... otherwise if the user types "Yes", it wouldn't match.

Comment: In general, I would recommend posting your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic solution. Haven't changed much from your code.

```
var qtwo = "";

while (qtwo != "yes" && qtwo != "no") {
    qtwo = prompt(" Do you like the color red (Yes/No) " + name);

    switch(qtwo) {

        case "yes":
            alert("I like the color red too!");
            break;

        case "no":
            alert("Okay.");
            break;

        default: 
            alert("Invalid answer! Please type only yes or no.");
    }
}
```

The main thing here is the outer while loop. Also, your `default` case shouldn't have the `if/else` that it originally had.

Answer (score 1):

The `var qtwo` should be moved to a separate line, and all the remaining code (including `qtwo = prompt(...)`) should be wrapped in a block with `while (qtwo != 'yes' && qtwo != 'no')`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap the prompt portion of your code in a while loop.

It's also a good idea to convert the stored response to lowercase to handle multiple versions of the same answer like 'Yes' or 'YES', to ensure that the loop terminates correctly.

Other common cases you might want to handle in the while/switch statement could be 'y' for yes, 'n' or a default 'nothing answered' case.

Here's some code that you can build off of:

```
var qtwo = "";

while (qtwo !== 'yes' && qtwo !== 'no') {
    qtwo = prompt(" Do you like the color red (Yes/No) " + name);
    qtwo = qtwo.toLowerCase();
}
```

// do stuff